# how do I tell cake where to look for coffee?

Tags: windows-7, coffeescript, git-bash, cakefile

Setting up the [express coffee app](https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee) that twilson63 built. It seems that cake can't find coffee, but they both are ok with `which`. Is there something else I need to do here? Here's my steps:

```
jcollum@DEVELOPER01 ~/dev/express-coffee-master
$ which coffee
/c/Users/jcollum/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
```

OK coffee is there.

```
jcollum@DEVELOPER01 ~/dev/express-coffee-master
$ which cake
/c/Users/jcollum/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
```

And so is cake.

```
jcollum@DEVELOPER01 ~/dev/express-coffee-master
$ cake
Cakefile defines the following tasks:

cake docs                 # Generate annotated source code with Docco
cake build
cake spec                 # Run Mocha tests
cake test                 # Run Mocha tests
cake dev                  # start dev env
cake debug                # start debug env
cake scaffold             # scaffold model/controller/test

  -n, --name         name of model to `scaffold`
```

Cake found a cakefile locally.

```
jcollum@DEVELOPER01 ~/dev/express-coffee-master
$ cake dev

c:\Users\jcollum\dev\express-coffee-master\node_modules\which\which.js:83
  throw new Error("not found: "+cmd)
        ^
Error: not found: coffee
    at Function.whichSync [as sync] (c:\Users\jcollum\dev\express-coffee-master\node_modules\which\which.js:83:9)
    at Object.options [as action] (c:\Users\jcollum\dev\express-coffee-master\Cakefile:121:17)
    at helpers.extend.invoke (c:\Users\jcollum\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\cake.js:44:26)
    at Object.exports.run (c:\Users\jcollum\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\cake.js:69:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\jcollum\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\cake:7:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Bzzzzttt! Nope. I suspect this is an issue with Windows 7 and node not playing all that nicely together.

Comment: That cake you refer to is not cakePHP, right? I think you are referring to cake.coffee (simplified version of make for CoffeeScript). I was confused by the tag.

Comment: @jimiyash yeah, must've selected the wrong tag; looks like benzado got it thanks benzado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the answer was to make sure I had a NODE_PATH in my env:

`export NODE_PATH=/c/Users/jcollum/AppData/Roaming/npm:/c/Users/jcollum/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules`

Either that, or adding the `node_modules` to my PATH in .bash_profile.

Got the idea here: https://github.com/replit/jsrepl/issues/56